# Laravel random internal server error

Tags: php, laravel, internal-server-error

I have a laravel application running on hosting and I get random Internal server errors and when I refresh the page everything is fine. Any ideas how can I make this internel server errors dissapear? I am 100% sure they appear randomly because sometimes it loads one page, other times it shows the error and when I see the error and refresh it shows the page correctly. I really need to understand how to fix this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do the pages take long to load? Did you trying to set `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` and see the error message?

Comment: @Youmy001 no, the pages do not take long to load, it shows the error immediately

Comment: Can you show us the error message?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get helpful answers, please include the error messages you are getting, so we can help you trace it.

Comment: Check you php error log and your Laravel error log.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when the page is refreshed fast. Laravel cannot read the config file or delay reading the config file. To solve the problem, it is better to cache the config.

```bash
php artisan config:cache
```